# Using LINQ, why can't Include() have a lambda expression when It's worked in the past?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this code to return all employees in my db. Each employee contains a collection of dependents.

```
var employees = _dbContext.Employees.Include(e => e.Dependents).ToList();
```

Problem is, it's telling me `Include()` can only take in a string. I **know** I've used it with a lambda expression in the past. Why won't it let me now?

If I do use `Include("Dependents")` it does work correctly, but I'd like to avoid relying on a string.

Comment: have you included the System.Data.Entity namespace? The lambda expression overload is an extension method.

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments, I tried using `System.Data.Entity` and it fixed my problem. Thanks!